First and second moments of OLS slope when Conditional Expectation Function is not linear in covariates
Suppose I have a joint distribution of "outcomes" and "covariates", $(Y,X)$. Define the slope of the population "best" linear predictor of $Y$ given $X$ as
$$\beta = \mathrm{argmin}_b \mathbb\ E[(Y-b'X)^2] = \mathbb E[XX']^{-1}\mathbb E[XY]$$
Let $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ be an i.i.d. sample from the population and let the sample least squares estimator be given by
$$\hat\beta = \left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_iX_i'\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i\right)$$
If the CEF $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ were linear-in-$X$, it is well known that OLS is unbiased and it is relatively straightforward to derive exact (i.e. not asymptotic, but finite-sample) variance formulas for $\hat\beta$ as well. Similarly, without the linearity assumption, the asymptotic distribution of $\hat\beta$ is straightforward to derive.
I would like to find general results about what we can say about the exact first and second moments of $\hat\beta$ when we depart from the linear CEF case. Ideally, I would like results which are as general as possible, but for the sake of concreteness, I am OK with assuming standard regularity conditions such as

$(Y,X)$ have all of their moments (I am also OK if there are known results that impose stronger conditions on the tails of $Y$ and/or $X$).
With $\mathbb E[Y | X = x]\equiv m(x)$ is continuous in $x$ (I am also OK if there are known results that impose more smoothnes on $m$).

Any references to get me started here would be appreciated.

Because "nonlinear" is very non-specific, and that leads to vagueness in your question, what can you tell us about how your model supposes the conditional expectation departs from linearity?

I tried my best to make my ask a bit more concrete, but to be frank, I am searching for general results that do not impose much about the relationship between $Y$ and $X$. Perhaps the answer is that results at that level of generality are unavailable, which is also useful information for me.

Those conditions aren't strong enough to establish bounds.

OLS will consistently estimate the best linear approximation to a nonlinear CEF, if that is a useful result. In particular, the normal equation $E [( −  ′ )] = 0$ implies by the law of iterated expectations that $E [( E [ | ] −  ′ )] = 0$ . Therefore, the BLP of $$ is also the BLP for the conditional expectation of $$ given $$ (from https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.02467, p14).

I am aware of the nice properties of OLS without too many assumptions, but I am specifically concerned about finite sample. For a bit of context, I am working on a trick that only works by improving finite-sample variance, so I really was hoping for some results on finite sample behavior of OLS under weak conditions.
